# Why is it said we do a knee extension in a deadlift?

Tags: deadlifts, knees

[This article](https://www.strongerbyscience.com/how-to-deadlift/) I'm reading says that we do a knee extension in the deadlift. But, I can't understand how.

I found this picture on the internet.

> [image]

In the above picture, we can see that the foot position is change with extnesion. However in the deadlift, the foot changes roughly at the same spot. So what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knee extension is the motion of the lower leg to return from a bent position (flexion) to a straight position. The muscles that cause this action are the quadriceps.

What you are showing in the picture is an example of open chain vs closed chain. In an open chain exercise, the distal (furthest away from the body) portion is free to move. Sitting in a chair and doing leg extensions is an example of this. Closed chain is where the foot would be fixed, and the upper leg moves such as in the squat.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the starting position of someone about to perform a deadlift.

[image: Picture of the person at the bottom of the deadlift]

You'll see that his knee come forward and are in fact slightly above the bar.

In order to complete the deadlift, you have to be standing with the knees locked.

[image: Picture of person at the top of the deadlift]

The process of your knee turning from a flexed position to an extended position is "knee extension".

---

> Foot position

In the photo you showed, the hips are locked in place but the foot is free to move.  In a deadlift, the feet are locked in place but the hips are free to move.  Those are the only way to do an extension. Either the hips or the feet have to be locked in place so the knee can extend straight. You wouldn't be able to move if both were locked in place, and you'd still have a bent knee if both moved in sync.

Answer (score 2):

Flexion and extension refers to the movement and relative position of *joints*, here the knee joint. Whether you move a limb under load, upside down, or free from gravity in space does not change anything about this terminology.

In a deadlift, both the hip and the knee joints are moving from a *bent* (flexed) position to a *straight* (extended) position, ie. both do an *extension*. They do so by activation of the *knee extensor* (M. quadriceps (femoris)) and the *hip extensors* (mainly gluteus maximus, as synergists the hamstrings).

Your picture does, indeed, picture an *open* kinetic chain as opposed to a *closed* kinetic chain like in a deadlift.  The main difference is that in an *open* kinetic chain, you can activate *muscles that do an extension (or flexion) of a single joint, in isolation* and without coordination with muscles moving other joints. In a closed kinetic chain, that is basically impossible.

That's why leg extension machines like this (open kinetic chain)
[image]
feel very different from leg presses (closed kinetic chain), even if we concentrate on the quadriceps only, which is activated in both cases.